# How to write a shell script to move several files from different sub-directories having same name to a different location?

Tags: shell

I have a file structure like that

```
/home/code/AXP1/file.dat
/home/code/AXP2/file.dat
/home/code/AXP3/file.dat
/home/code/AXP4/file.dat
```

I want to move all the files with `.dat` extension under the sub-directories `APX1`, `APX2`, `APX3`, `APX4`, etc. to a specific location, say `/home/BOX` with the name like `file1.dat`, `file2.dat`, `file3.dat`, `file4.dat`, etc.

So, could you please give a an idea how to write a Linux shell script to do the above task.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
mv /home/code/APX[1-4]/file.dat /home/BOX/
```

If you want to keep the number of the folder they were, you can do this:

```
for i in {1..4}
do
  mv /home/code/APX$i/file.dat /home/BOX/file$i.dat
done
```

If you have more than 4 folder, let's say `n`, change 4 for `n`.